# Find resource by slug in nested resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I have following routes

```
 resources :shops do
    resources :categories
  end
```

And when I visit this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/shops/rabin-shop/categories
```

I first want to find the shop by using slug 'rabin-shop', then I can filter the categories of products that belong to that shop. In my controller I have tried to implement

```
    def find_shop
       @shop = Shop.find(params[:slug])
    end
```

But this is not working. I know this is not how to find in nested resource. I am using friendly_id gem . I cannot do something like current_user.shop because I want the page to be accessed even when the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the freindly_id gem, this is how you find a record by it's slug :

```
 def find_shop
   # params[:shop_id] if nested
   @shop = Shop.friendly.find(params[:id])
 end
```